# $.getScript(): Loading js scripts conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible in $.getScript() to create a condition where if the first js script fails to load - for whatever reason - then run the second js? Like a backup?

Any way to make this work with jQuery 1.2 and/or 1.4?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're using jQuery 1.5 or greater then $.getScript() returns a Promise so you can attach a function to both success and failure. They show an example in their documentation where they attach to fail like so:

```
$.getScript("ajax/test.js")
.done(function(script, textStatus) {
  console.log( textStatus );
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
  $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

There's no reason why you couldn't do another $.getScript() within the function that .fail() calls.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the docs for this? It's quite clear, as of jquery 1.5, you can use .fail()

```
$.getScript("ajax/test.js")
.done(function(script, textStatus) {
  console.log( textStatus );
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
  $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

earlier than that, you use the global ajax error:

```
$( "div.log" ).ajaxError(function(e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
  if (settings.dataType=='script') {
    $(this).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
  }
});
```

or more pratically, just don't rely on getscript, and use the .ajax fn:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success,
  error:function(){
    //load the second script here
  }
});
```